# End Process Created by PHP exec in Ubuntu using Apache

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, memory, process

I have an Ubuntu VM running in VirtualBox that hosts a server using Apache.  The concept of the server is to accept HTTP POST requests, store them in a MySQL database and then execute a Python script with the relevant POST data to be displayed in a Discord channel.

The process itself is working but each time the PHP script calls the Python script, a new process is created that never actually ends.  After a few hours of receiving live data the server runs out of available memory due to the amount of lingering processes.  The PHP script has the following exec call as the last line of code;

`exec("python3 main.py $DATA");`

I would like to come up with a way to actually kill the processes created from this exec command (using user www-data), either in the Python file after the script is executed or automatically with an Apache setting that I probably just do not know about.

When running the following command in a terminal I can see the different processes;

`ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax | sort -b -k3 -r`

There are 3 separate processes that show up, 1 referencing the actual python3 exec command as marked up in PHP;

- `9903 www-data  0.4 python3 main.py DATADATADATADATADATADATA`

Then another process showing the more common -k start commands;

- `9907 www-data  0.1 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start`

And lastly another process very similar to the PHP exec command;

- `9902 www-data  0.0 sh -c python3 main.py DATADATADATADATADATADATA`

**How can I ensure Apache cleans these processes up - OR what do I need to add into my Python or PHP code to appropriately exec a Python script without leaving behind processes?**

Answer (score 0):

Didn't realize the `exec` command in php would wait for a return output indefinitely.  Added this to the end of the string I was using in my `exec` call;  `> /dev/null &`

i.e.: `exec("python3 main.py $DATA > /dev/null &");`